# How to make combination of two fields distinct in Android Room database in which ("valueA", "valueB"), ("valueB", "valueA") are 1 entry

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I want to insert records into a FriendRequest table and want to make the values distinct so that if **userA** sends a request to **userB** or **userB** sends a request to **userA** the entry in the table is **only one**.

Is there a way to make this possible? I have the following code but this doesn't give the desired behaviour

```kotlin
@Entity(tableName = "friendship", indices = [
    Index(value = ["requesterId", "receiverId"], unique = true)])
data class DtoFriendRequest{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but try to make the unique index on max and min value as follows:

```
Max("requesterId", "receiverId"), min ("requesterId", "receiverId")
```

Comment: I'll try this out